# Clear input buffer: Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, input

I've just started with VB in VS2010 and attempting to write a simple console calculator. However, i can't get it to wait to display the output. The console window closes immediately even after putting a Console.Read(). I guess the input buffer from my ReadLine() still has some valid characters. I'll paste the code here:

Sub Main()

```
    Dim num1 As Double
    Dim num2 As Double
    Dim op As Char
    Dim ans As Double

    Console.Write("Enter first number:")

    num1 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

    Console.Write("Enter second number:")
    num2 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

    Console.Write("Enter an operator:")
    op = ChrW(Console.Read())

    Select Case op
        Case "+"
            ans = num1 + num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

        Case "-"
            ans = num1 - num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())


        Case "*"
            ans = num1 * num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

        Case "/"
            If num2 <> 0 Then
                ans = num1 / num2
                Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())
            Else : Console.WriteLine("Error: Division by zero")
            End If

    End Select

    Console.Read()

End Sub
```

I've noticed that i need to put 3 Console.Read()'s at the end of the code to finally get the console to wait. Why is this happening?

Comment: I assume you're not getting any error-messages of any kind? What happens if you try `Console.ReadLine()` instead of just `Console.Read()?`

Comment: @Kjartan There are no error messages. Using Console.ReadLine() had no effect on it i.e. it still won't wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the end and you'll see what's happening:

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.Read().ToString())
Console.WriteLine(Console.Read().ToString())
Console.Read()
```

The [`Console.Read` for `op` is unblocked when you hit return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx), but the carriage return/line feed sequence is in the buffer and hasn't been consumed.  So two additional `Console.Read` calls clear the CR (Dec: 13)/LF (Dec: 10) and then the third blocks like you want.

`Console.ReadLine` doesn't work because it consumes the CR/LF and there's nothing then to block existing the app.  Two `Console.ReadLine` calls or `Console.ReadLine` followed by `Console.Read` would work.

Comment: @jim-oneil Exactly, i'm getting 13 and 10. So does this mean that i have to write Console.Read() twice every time i use Console.Read() for input?
Thanks!

Comment: yes, assuming you're following it up with another read and you don't care about the CR/LF.  I don't see a flush type method.  Of course you could use ReadLine or maybe ReadKey to read in the operator

Answer (score 1):

Use Console.Readkey():

```
Dim num1 As Double
Dim num2 As Double
Dim op As Char
Dim ans As Double

Console.Write("Enter first number:")

num1 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

Console.Write("Enter second number:")
num2 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

Console.Write("Enter an operator:")
op = ChrW(Console.Read())

Select Case op
    Case "+"
        ans = num1 + num2
        Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

    Case "-"
        ans = num1 - num2
        Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())


    Case "*"
        ans = num1 * num2
        Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

    Case "/"
        If num2 <> 0 Then
            ans = num1 / num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())
        Else : Console.WriteLine("Error: Division by zero")
        End If

End Select

Console.ReadKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried as your code but change "op = ChrW(Console.Read())" to "op = Console.ReadLine()", and it run well

```
Sub Main()

    Dim num1 As Double
    Dim num2 As Double
    Dim op As Char
    Dim ans As Double

    Console.Write("Enter first number:")

    num1 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

    Console.Write("Enter second number:")
    num2 = CType(Console.ReadLine(), Double)

    Console.Write("Enter an operator:")
    op = Console.ReadLine()

    Select Case op
        Case "+"
            ans = num1 + num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

        Case "-"
            ans = num1 - num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())


        Case "*"
            ans = num1 * num2
            Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())

        Case "/"
            If num2 <> 0 Then
                ans = num1 / num2
                Console.WriteLine("Result=" + ans.ToString())
            Else : Console.WriteLine("Error: Division by zero")
            End If

    End Select

    Console.Read()

End Sub
```